# Mono Compiler as a Service recompiling ASP.NET MVC site at runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mono

I found a fascinating link talking about using the Mono Compiler as Service to dynamically compile Controller classes at runtime:

http://blog.fusonic.net/2011/04/scripting-asp-net-mvc-controllers-at-runtime/

But it only works for Controllers. Can anyone out there shed any light on whether it would be possible to have an entire project evaluated at runtime? Although it would mean less compile-time error checking, it could still be a huge productivity boost.

Comment: Why would it be a productivity boost? Sounds like you're giving all the advantages of the pre-compiled language with very little to get in return.

Comment: I often work on large projects- recompiling the entire thing after changing one single line in a class just seems wasteful. Whenever I've used languages like Python I've loved being able to reload more or less instantly. I'd argue that you're not losing any advantages- presumably (in my possibly imaginary world where this works) you can hit build and still get compile-time checking. But also sometimes just make a quick change and load. ASP.NET web sites used to be able to do it.

Comment: So instead of you waiting for it to compile the first person to hit your site will have to wait for it to compile?

Comment: No, no... I'm not suggesting using this in a production environment. Just for development, and it would work like the old ASP.NET CodeFile model did- just that .cs file gets recompiled on load, not the whole project.

Comment: @Alastair, i am compiling my controllers dynamically using mono (now I will change it to use Roslyn) for the same reasons that you exposed, my project is BIG and compile it again and again takes a long time. However, let me share my experince with you, the profit to do that is not enough, I mean, you win some time changing the controller code and pressing F5 but, when you have any problem you have to debug and to do that you have to compile and set a breakpoint and start the common dance F10, F10, Quick watch, Run to cursor, etc.
I hope my experince be usuful for you, believe me it not worth.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to dynamically compile everything you put into the **App_Code** folder (including controllers, custom HTML and Url helpers etc) if you convert your project to the **Web site project** type [(How to do it is described here)](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/08/15/How-To-Use-ASPNET-MVC-in-Website-rather-than-Web-Application-Project.aspx) without a need for the compiler as a service.

The drawbacks are that you can't dynamically compile referenced libraries with your business logic or database access library. And there is a obvious performance drawback which can be partially eliminated by the IIS application warmup module.

Some argue that there is a security problem with deploying all source codes on your production servers, but the scripting world (Ruby on rails, python web framworks, php, node.js etc) doesn't seems to be much worried about this issue, and as far as you don't obfuscate your dll's there isn't much difference in the security of your intelectual property.